# On Hover event in Label in Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am creating one App in appmaker in which I want to have some code on onHover() event (On Label), I can only see 4 events available

1. onAttach
2. onDetach
3. onDataLoad
4. onClick

How can I call my methods on onHover event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Maker doesn't provide `onHover` event handler out of the box, however you can add event listener for [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) or [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) event on your own:

```javascript
// client script
function doMagic(event) {
  // do the magic here
}

// onAttach widget's event
widget.getElement().addEventListener('mouseenter', doMagic);


// onDetach widget's event
widget.getElement().removeEventListener('mouseenter', doMagic);
```